# inner join with invoice

Tags: sql, join

I made this SQL query and got sale orders that I needed, but I still need to join this sale orders with their invoices and filter only those sale orders that have invoices with `state != 'draft'`.

But can't find a way to join with sale orders with invoices.

I think there is table called `sale_order_invoice_rel` but can't figure out how to join and filter correctly

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT so.id

FROM stock_picking sp

INNER JOIN stock_move sm

ON sp.id = sm.picking_id

INNER JOIN procurement_order po

ON sm.procurement_id = po.id

INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol

ON po.sale_line_id = sol.id

INNER JOIN sale_order so

ON sol.order_id = so.id

WHERE so.invoice_status = 'to invoice' and sp.state = 'done'
ORDER BY so.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them like this.

```sql
    FROM stock_picking sp
                       INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON sp.id = sm.picking_id
                       INNER JOIN procurement_order po ON sm.procurement_id = po.id
                       INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol ON po.sale_line_id = sol.id 
                       INNER JOIN sale_order so ON sol.order_id = so.id
                       -- keep join them like this
                       INNER JOIN sale_order_invoice_rel so_inv_rel on so.id = so_inv_rel.order_id
                       INNER JOIN account_invoice inv on so_inv_rel.invoice_id = inv.id

    WHERE 

            so.invoice_status = 'to invoice'
            and sp.state = 'done'       
            and inv.state != 'draft'
```

Using `INNER JOIN` will show only sale order that have an invoice.

Comment: If you want to make sure that the joining is happening correctly remove the where clause.